# How can I make a Collection of Integer using a List of "Person"?

Tags: java, list, object, collections

Hi I'm new here and I have a Question.

I have this Object.

```
    public Person(int id,String name, int age){ 
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;   
    }
```

And I want to create a Collection studentsIds.

Until now I have

```
    List<Person> students=new ArrayList<Person>(); 

    Collection<Integer> studentsIds=new ArrayList<Person>(students);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why would you want two sets of data? The Person class contains all the ids. If you ever need a list of the ids just iterate through the student list

Comment: You may want to check out a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) which is a collection of KeyValues. It may be closer to what you are trying to achieve depending on your goals with this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do it like that. Both are different data types. So create an Integer collection and then Look into persons collection.

```
List<Integer> studentsIds=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then

```
for (Person p : students){

  studentsIds.add(p.age); // change to p.id if you need

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do something like this

```
for(Person s: students) studentIds.add(s.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

While others stated a right answer, you can achieve that also in Java 8 using lambda expressions :

```
List<Integer> studentsIds = students.stream()
                                    .map(student -> student.id)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Without Java 8 lambdas you could use anonymous classes with the help of Guava library:

```
List<Integer> studentsIds = Lists.transform(students, getStudentId);

private final Function<Person, Integer> getStudentId =
        new Function<Person, Integer>() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Integer apply(@Nullable Person student) {
                return student == null ? null : student.id;
            }
        };
```